# How to check if the Last Column is different from the Second last Column? Unresolved attribute reference 'any' for class 'bool

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series with dtype: Boolean

If the second last and last column are different from each other then do the part in the If-Condition.

I have two different solutions, but with both I get an error:

**Unresolved attribute reference 'any' for class 'bool'**

Solution 1:

```
difference = result[result.columns[-1]] != result[result.columns[-2]]
    if difference.any():
        ...
    else:
        print("Error!")
```

Solution 2:

```
difference = result[result.columns[-1]] != result[result.columns[-2]]
    if True in difference.values:
        ...
    else:
        print("Error!")
```

Is there a third Solution where I dont get error?

Comment: but `'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`, what's your current `result`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry result is a Dataframe. But result.colums[-1] can be seen as a Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need compare Series there are no column names, ouput is bool `True` or `False`:

```
difference = result[-1] != result[-2]
    if difference:
        ...
    else:
        print("Error!")
```

If need compare columns in `result` DataFrame and [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) failed you can use [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
difference = result.iloc[:, -1] != result.iloc[:, -2]
if np.any(difference):
    ...
else:
    print("Error!")
```

Comment: Sorry result is a Dataframe. But the second Solution you provided doesnt solve the problems. I think the problem lies on the side of .any()

Comment: @SebastianHeeg - What is `print (difference)` ?

Comment: Difference is a Series with dtype: Boolean

Comment: @SebastianHeeg - hmm, what about `np.any(difference)` ?